# Firefox 5 not loading css files in websites

Tags: css, firefox

I have installed FF5 but i have seen after 2-3 days it stops loading css from sometimes.

Then i need to restart 2-3 times , then it works fine . But same thing happens after 2-3 days.

where is the problem

EDIT:

I see that in FF for e.g  if the site uses `http://www.abc.com/style.css` then if i enter that address in FF address bar then it says `file not found` but if use same in `IE or Chrome` then file opens. whats the problem. It does it only for few sites not all

Comment: It sounds like it could be a cache problem if it works for a bit and then stops working after a length of time. Try emptying your cache to see if that helps. Worst case, set your Firefox to empty cache upon closing.

Comment: Can you try if it works with [a new Firefox profile](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing-profiles)? (Keep the old one as a backup!)

Comment: I have edited the questions for more details

Comment: Do you have any (rogue) extensions installed?